# iOS Swift assign variable value with conditional

Tags: ios, swift

back in objective-c i can assign value of a variable with a result of conditional

EX :

```
int b = 10
int c = 11
int a = b!=c ? 90 : 100;
```

But now on swift i cannot do that no more.

```
var b = 10
var c = 11
var a = b > c ? 90 : 100
```

the code above always highlight the `var a` line as error with desc : `Expected expression` with suggestion of adding `;`

is there a way to assign variable with conditional with swift?

thanks!

Comment: what are `b` and `c`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @wain b and c are just an example, i'll edit  the question
@Sulthan the error always `expecting arguments`

Comment: Your example works perfectly in playground. Maybe you just have some syntax error

Comment: @MaximKosov, yes, apparently it caused by spaces between variables and the operator.
thank you for checking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your problem. you are trying to write code like this

```
  var b = 10
  var c = 11
  var value = b >c ? 90 : 100
```

which is wrong and gives you an error.

instead write code with extra space after >

```
var a = b > c ? 90 : 100
```

Comment: yes, that was the wrong thing

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot figure out the code because somewhere above (part which we cannot see) you have some unrelated invalid code.

If you paste this and only this to Playground, it works without any problem.

```
var b = 10
var c = 11
var a = b > c ? 90 : 100
```

Comment: i made the above code in playground too, so there is no other part.
i found out that it was because i don't make spaces between variables and the operator in `b > c`
but, thank you for the answer.
 it also give me more case to lookout if things like this occur again

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside an function rather than declaring it global property.

```
        var b: Int = 10
        var c: Int = 11
        var a:Int = b > c ? 90 : 100
```